# How to get offset in logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

In order to sort logs with same timestamps, I need offset. Does anyone know how to get offset in each event of logstash?

Purpose here is to sort the logs as they appeared in the original log file.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy problem to solve. There are two dates that Logstash can leverage:

1. The exact time the event was ingested
2. The time encoded in the event itself.

Your best bet here is to stash the ingest-time to a field; for a log-file read in series, events in the same second will be ingested at slightly different times, so ordering by ingest-time will reorder your logs. Your filter stream could look something like this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "ingest_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }
  }
  grok { some things }
  date {
    match = [ "SYSLOGTIMESTAMP", ISO8601 ]
  }
}
```

In this case, `@timestamp` would be set to the time encoded in the event, and `ingest_timestamp` would be set to the ingested timestamp. Order first by `@timestamp` and then by `ingest_timestamp` and you will reorder your events into the order they probably arrived in the logfile.